# Wanted to arise microphone permission when mic button is pressed in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-permissions, speech-to-text, microphone

I added a feature in my mobile app which is speech to text in flutter. I used speech_to_text flutter package for enable this feature.
When I go to the chatting page that time app taking microphone permission. But I don't want that. I want when I press the microphone button, that time it will take permission.
How could I do it?

I added  this permission into my AndroidManifest file.

This is my function:

```
 // Speech to text
  void _startListening() async {
    PermissionStatus status = await Permission.microphone.request();
    if (status != PermissionStatus.granted) {
      final snackBar = SnackBar(
        /// need to set following properties for best effect of awesome_snackbar_content
        elevation: 0,
        behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        content: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
            bottom: 55.0,
          ),
          child: AwesomeSnackbarContent(
            title: 'Please Turn On Mic!',
            message:
                'Microphone access denied. Please enable microphone access in your device settings.',

            /// change contentType to ContentType.success, ContentType.warning or ContentType.help for variants
            contentType: ContentType.failure,
          ),
        ),
      );

      // ignore: use_build_context_synchronously
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
        ..hideCurrentSnackBar()
        ..showSnackBar(snackBar);
      return;
    }

    _speechToText.listen(
      onResult: (result) {
        setState(() {
          _text = result.recognizedWords;
          textEditingController.text = _text;
        });
      },
    );
    setState(() {
      _isListening = true;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

Future<bool> _requestMicrophonePermission() async {
  // Check if permission status is granted
  var status = await Permission.microphone.status;

  // Request permission only if not already granted
  if (status != PermissionStatus.granted) {
    final result = await Permission.microphone.request();
    if (result == PermissionStatus.granted) {
      // Permission granted, proceed with speech recognition
      return true;
    } else if (result == PermissionStatus.permanentDenied) {
      // Handle permanent denial: Open app settings or provide instructions
      await openAppSettings();
      return false;
    } else {
      // Other permission states (e.g., denied)
      return false;
    }
  } else {
    // Permission already granted, proceed with speech recognition
    return true;
  }
}
```

Here you can use a method for microphone permission.

I write here a demo code for UI,

```
class MyChatPage extends StatefulWidget {
  // ...

  @override
  State<MyChatPage> createState() => _MyChatPageState();
}

class _MyChatPageState extends State<MyChatPage> {
  bool _isListening = false;

  Future<void> _startListening() async {
    if (await _requestMicrophonePermission()) {
      // Start speech recognition using the speech_to_text package
      // ...
    } else {
      // Inform the user that permission was denied
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text('Microphone permission is required for speech recognition.'),
        ),
      );
    }
    setState(() {
      _isListening = true;
    });
  }

  Future<void> _stopListening() async {
    // Stop speech recognition using the speech_to_text package
    // ...
    setState(() {
      _isListening = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      // ...
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _isListening ? _stopListening : _startListening,
        child: Icon(_isListening ? Icons.stop : Icons.mic),
      ),
      // ...
    );
  }
}
```